Real part of complex solution to PDE still solution?
EDIT:
I updated my question in order to make it more clear. Here is my concrete problem:

I am trying to solve some PDE of the form:
$$\partial_t u = L(x,u) \quad , \qquad u \equiv u(t,x) \tag{1}$$
with $L$ having real coefficients and being linear in $u$. Numerically integrating this equation suggests that there is a real solution. Assume now that $u$ is complex. Since this PDE is linear, $\mathrm{Re}(u)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(u)$ are solutions to the equation as well. In fact, they satisfy the same equation and must therefore coincide. Hence it doesn't really matter whether one calls $u$ real or $u$ complex, as $\mathrm{Re}(u) = \mathrm{Im}(u)$ must hold.
However, due to linearity I can also make the ansatz
$$u(t,x) = e^{i\omega t} f_{\omega}(x) \quad , \qquad \omega \in \mathbb{C}$$
such that the equation becomes
$$i \omega f_{\omega} = L(x,f_{\omega}) \tag{2}$$
Given some existence and uniqueness property, how are the solutions of the two equations connected? Since one is obtained by the other, I assume that they should share the same set of solutions, otherwise uniqueness is violated (right?). Is the answer to this, that solutions to the above equation (1) are linear combinations of solutions to equation (2)?

Assume now furthermore that the PDE is no longer linear and that it rather has the form
$$\partial_t u = L(x,u) + |u|^2 u$$
I suspect that it is of the essence here whether I want $u$ to be real or to be complex. For complex $u$, I can once again make the same ansatz such that
$$i \omega f_{\omega} = L(x,f) + |f|^2 f$$
which reduces the equation from PDE to ODE. This doesn't work for $u$ real. Is there some way in which real $u$ or complex $u$ are connected, e.g. the solution for $u$ real is just the real part of the solution for $u$ complex? Or does the nonlinearity cause these equations to be fundamentally different when assuming $u$ to be real or $u$ to be complex?

Could it be that $L(x,u)=-\nabla \cdot (A  \nabla u)$ is an elliptic operator, say the Laplacian $-\Delta$? That looks a lot like a non-linear Schrödinger equation to me then, since the property of the operator $H=L+|u|^2=-\Delta + |u|^2$ having a real-valued function as a solution comes down to the properties of $L$.

Nearly. I wanted to provide a MWE, the actual equation is indeed $\square_g u  - |u|^2 u = 0$ with $\square$ being d'Alemberts operator with respect to the metric $g$ of a curved spacetime.
